# DAO. Many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, oop, repository-pattern, dao

How to handle many to many relationships when using DAO pattern? Is DAO responsible for linking two entities using 3-rd Link table? For example I have 2 entities: `Customer` and `Product`.

And I need to provide methods like:

```
public void assignCustomerToProduct(...);
public List<Product> getSelledProducts(long customerId);
```

This methods requires using 3-rd table as Linkage table. 
Is `CustomerDao` responsible for providing this method? Or it's better to exclude this methods into service-layer?

Comment: BTW, we don't have "Selled" in English. Maybe, you mean "Sold" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the objects should own the relationship. So for example positions are only saved when you save an Employee.

If you do this, then Employee becomes a (a bit) like an Aggregate Root (if you're talking about DDD repositories). The repository is then responsible from creating the position if required and inserting the many-to-many entry in the link table.

If Position is an aggregate root itself, then the EmployeeRepository is only responsible for updating the link table, but is not responsible for persisting Positions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use any Repository pattern. Someone edited my question and added `repository-pattern` tag. In real I use _only_ DAO patterns and even more I don't know what is Repository pattern and how to use it. My  question accords to DAO pattern. Or more specially - `GenericDAO`. P.S. I use JDBC. ... And if you can provide some advantages of repository pattern over DAO and why it's better to me use Repository instead DAO I ready to change my code :)

Comment: They are very similar, but Repository is used with Domain Driven Design (DDD) and it has a few restrictions about what it should do. I think most of what I wrote above still applies. So for example, your EmployeeDAO can responsible for storing the Employee and the rows in the link table between employees and positions. Have a truly bidirectional relationship where storing either will persist something to the link table is a lot of work, and might not be worth it.

Comment: `If Position is an aggregate root itself, then the EmployeeRepository is only responsible for updating the link table, but is not responsible for persisting Positions.` So it's not bad to have methods like I mention inside `EmployyDAO`?

Comment: Kind of. EmployeeDAO should update the link table whenever you want to save an Employee. This doesn't mean that the DAO will have a method to just insert a row in the link table. In this way, your application is properly OO and how you persist data is a detail.